# CentOS 7 Disk space missing

Tags: centos, filesystems, partition, disk, fdisk

I have recently installed CentOS on my laptop which has two disks, SSD(32GB) + HDD(1TB).
During installation I had set `/boot`(2GB) and `/boot/efi`(500MB) on SSD while rest all partitions on HDD.
I want to utilize the leftover SSD for other compute intensive tasks but I don't see it fully.

Output of `fdisk /dev/sdb + p` command:

```
Command (m for help): p           

Disk /dev/sdb: 32.0 GB, 32017047552 bytes, 62533296 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: gpt
Disk identifier: 8807D20C-1A48-4014-85CA-FBFF7F8D2085


#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1         2048       976895    476M  EFI System      EFI System Partition
 2       976896      5273599    2.1G  Microsoft basic 
 3      5273600     33902591   13.7G  Linux LVM
```

In the above output, it shows around 16GB.
So How do I see the other invisible 16GB of SSD?
And how do I group the two together(13.7GB + other invisible 16GB), so that I could have around 30GB of SSD for use.

Comment: what is the result of `lsblk | grep sdb` ?

Comment: root@localhost software]# lsblk | grep sdb
sdb               8:16   0  29.8G  0 disk 
├─sdb1            8:17   0   476M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sdb2            8:18   0   2.1G  0 part /boot
└─sdb3            8:19   0  13.7G  0 part

Comment: you know you can edit original post with result from comands we ask you. ?  Your HDD doesn't seems fully use either (600 GB / 1 TB). on `sdb` delete `sdb3`  and recreate it with max size from `fdisk`

Comment: Ill go with CentOS reinstallation in single disk(HDD). and mount SSD after installation.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I see the other invisible 16GB of SSD? And how do I group the
> two together(13.7GB + other invisible 16GB), so that I could have
> around 30GB of SSD for use.

You already see your other 16GB of SSD:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 32.0 GB, 32017047552 bytes, 62533296 sectors
```

Since you are using LVM, extend the disk size with the `pvresize`.
Check your disk linked to LVM with `pvdisplay`

```
pvresize /dev/sdb3
```

Then extend your logical volume, get the name with `lvdisplay`

```
lvextend -l 100%FREE <Name of your volume>
```

**EDIT:**
The second have of your disk space is included in the Volume group (LVM) called Centos, with your HDD. So it's not missing, but you will not be able to select it for your computing as you need, unless your do your installation from scratch and redo the partitioning.

Comment: I ran commands and getting sdb3 not found. [root@localhost software]# pvresize /dev/sdb3
  Physical volume "/dev/sdb3" changed
  1 physical volume(s) resized or updated / 0 physical volume(s) not resized
[root@localhost software]# lvdisplay /dev/sdb3
  Volume group "sdb3" not found
  Cannot process volume group sdb3
[root@localhost software]#

Comment: `pvresize /dev/sdb3` _Physical volume "/dev/sdb3" changed 1 physical volume(s) resized or updated_
just run `lvdisplay`, without other arguments. I should display a name in the output

Comment: I can see three Logical Volume but none of them belong to SSD. They all belong to HDD. Perhaps I would need to make SSD LVM. LV Path-/dev/centos/swap, LV Name-swap.
LV Path-/dev/centos/home, LV Name-home.
LV Path-/dev/centos/root, LV Name-root.

Comment: Can you give the result of `vgdisplay` and `lvdisplay` ?

Comment: [root@localhost software]# vgdisplay
--- Volume group ---
VG Name            centos
System ID             
Format                lvm2
Metadata Areas        2
Metadata Sequence No  10
VG Access             read/write
VG Status             resizable
MAX LV                0
Cur LV                3
Open LV               3
Max PV                0
Cur PV                2
Act PV                2
VG Size               <673.42 GiB
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              172395
Alloc PE / Size       172393 / 673.41 GiB
Free  PE / Size       2 / 8.00 MiB
VG UUID  Jz1NG2

Comment: [root@localhost software]# lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/centos/swap
  LV Name                swap
  VG Name                centos
  LV UUID                bcoTMk-GeOw-nm55-seoH-RUAu-2uDU-kZBIdN
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost, 2021-06-08 15:59:28 +0530
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
LV Size                7.75 GiB
Current LE             1984
Segments               1
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     256
Block device      253:1

Comment: --- Logical volume ---
 LV Path                /dev/centos/home
LV Name                home
VG Name                centos
LV UUID                2AfHoQ-I8FN-OzD3-MDVF-cU0K-zJRD-NgMSSI
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Creation host, time localhost, 2021-06-08 15:59:28 +0530
LV Status              available
# open                 1
LV Size                465.66 GiB
Current LE             119209
Segments               1
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     256
Block device           253:2

Comment: --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/centos/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                centos
  LV UUID                D7kGJc-t3FK-NhkB-l2JT-clFY-P8UN-DrTn7K
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost, 2021-06-08 15:59:31 +0530
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                200.00 GiB
  Current LE             51200
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0

Comment: It seems that your disk is used `Cur PV 2 Act PV 2 VG Size <673.42 GiB`, it is in the LVM, grouped with the HDD.
If you want to have it back, you will need to redo your installation from scratch.
Hope it helped

Comment: I was beginning to consider reinstallation. This time I would put everything in single disk (HDD-1TB) and after installation of CentOS, I would mount full SSD where I would keep heavy computation software.
Thanks for the help.